# Create symfony1.4 custom component for custom table

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

I am working in a project which is using `symfony 1.4.` I am new to symfony, so i am not able to get the structure clear. Also its a old version. Can you anyone please guide/give some link for me for creating the `symfony 1.4` custom component for my custom table

**eg:table**

```
user(id, age, roles)
```

I am new to stackoverflow.